# Como acceder a un HTML dentro de otro HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

tengo una duda. No se si esto es siquiera posible.
Resulta que estoy instalando unos widgets de TrustPilot en un sitio. La cuestión es que si bien tienen selectores están anidados dentro de otro documento HTML.
Digamos que lo que ellos te dan para instalar es un Script de JS y un DIV con algo asi.

```
<!-- TrustBox widget - Micro Star -->
        <div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="blablabla"
            data-businessunit-id="blablabla" data-style-height="24px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light">
            <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.mipagina.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
        </div>
        <!-- End TrustBox widget -->
```

Luego con las herramientas de Chrome puedo ver como ese DIV genera un  tag y dentro de eso todo un documento HTML donde están los elementos del Widget con sus clases y ID's, pero no se como identificarlos con CSS, obviamente ya he intentado con sus clases y ID's pero como están anidados dentro de otro documento HTML no funciona. IDEAS ????

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" title="Customer reviews powered by Trustpilot" loading="auto" src="https://widget.trustpilot.com/trustboxes/blabla123/index.html?templateId=blabla123&amp;businessunitId=blabla123#locale=en-GB&amp;styleHeight=24px&amp;styleWidth=100%25&amp;theme=light" style="position: relative; height: 24px; width: 100%; border-style: none; display: block; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <title>Trustpilot Custom Widget</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

    <!-- polyfill used by Sentry for IE -->
    <script nomodule="" src="https://polyfills.trustpilot.com/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise%2CObject.assign%2CString.prototype.includes%2CNumber.isNaN"></script>

    <style>
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote::before,blockquote::after,q::before,q::after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}body{font-family:"Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial","sans-serif";font-size:12px}b,strong{font-weight:700}.bold-underline,.tp-widget-empty-vertical__title,.tp-widget-empty-horizontal__title{font-family:"Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial","sans-serif";font-weight:500}@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active){.bold-underline,.tp-widget-empty-vertical__title,.tp-widget-empty-horizontal__title{font-weight:600}}*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}.hidden{display:none}.tp-widget-loader,.tp-widget-fallback{left:50%;position:absolute;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%)}#fallback-logo{display:none}.no-svg #fallback-logo{display:inline-block}.tp-widget-wrapper{height:100%;margin:0 auto;max-width:750px;position:relative}.tp-stars .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#dcdce6}.tp-stars .tp-star__shape{fill:#fff}.tp-stars--1 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+1) .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars--1 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+1) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#ff3722}.tp-stars--2 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+2) .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars--2 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+2) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#ff8622}.tp-stars--3 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+3) .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars--3 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+3) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#ffce00}.tp-stars--4 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+4) .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars--4 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+4) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#73cf11}.tp-stars--5 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+5) .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars--5 .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+5) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#00b67a}.tp-stars--1--half .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+2) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#ff3722}.tp-stars--2--half .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+3) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#ff8622}.tp-stars--3--half .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+4) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#ffce00}.tp-stars--4--half .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+4) .tp-star__canvas,.tp-stars--4--half .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+4) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#00b67a}.tp-stars--4--half .tp-star:nth-of-type(-n+5) .tp-star__canvas--half{fill:#00b67a}.tp-widget-loader,.tp-widget-fallback{max-width:50%;text-align:center;width:400vh}.tp-widget-loader svg,.tp-widget-fallback svg{width:100%}@media screen and (min-width: 400px){.tp-widget-loader,.tp-widget-fallback{max-width:200px}}.tp-widget-loader--loaded{opacity:0}.bold-underline{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(25,25,25,0.6)}.bold-underline:hover{border-color:#191919}.dark{color:#fff}.dark a{color:#fff}.dark .bold-underline:not(.bold-underline--single-theme){border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6)}.dark .bold-underline:not(.bold-underline--single-theme):hover{border-color:#fff}.dark .tp-logo__text{fill:#fff}.dark .tp-widget-loader .tp-logo__text{fill:#191919}html{height:100%;overflow:hidden}body{color:#191919;height:100%;line-height:1;min-width:100%;overflow:hidden;width:1px}img{border:0}svg{display:block;width:100%}a{color:#191919;text-decoration:none}.tp-widget-empty-vertical{-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center}.tp-widget-empty-vertical__title{font-size:18px;margin:0 0 12px;text-align:center}.tp-widget-empty-vertical__stars{margin:0 0 8px;width:150px}.tp-widget-empty-vertical__subtitle-wrapper{display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row}.tp-widget-empty-vertical__subtitle{-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;font-size:14px;text-align:center}.tp-widget-empty-vertical__logo{margin:0 0 5px 5px;width:90px}.tp-widget-empty-horizontal{-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;height:100%;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center}.tp-widget-empty-horizontal__title{font-size:14px;text-align:center}.tp-widget-empty-horizontal__logo{margin:0 0 5px 5px;width:90px}@media screen and (max-width: 300px){.tp-widget-empty-vertical__subtitle-wrapper{-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.tp-widget-empty-vertical__logo{margin:5px 0 0}.tp-widget-empty-horizontal{-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.tp-widget-empty-horizontal__logo{margin:0}}.tp-widget-wrapper{text-align:center}.tp-widget-trustscore{font-size:14px;font-weight:500;margin:0 0 6px}.tp-widget-stars{margin:0 auto 6px;max-width:100%;width:110px}.tp-widget-logo{margin:0 auto;width:65px}@media screen and (min-width: 200px){.tp-widget-wrapper{font-size:0}.tp-widget-trustscore,.tp-widget-stars{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle}.tp-widget-trustscore{font-size:18px;margin:0 12px 8px 0}.tp-widget-stars{margin:0 0 8px;width:100px}.tp-widget-logo{width:72px}}@media screen and (min-width: 260px){.tp-widget-stars{margin:0 8px 8px 0}.tp-widget-logo{display:inline-block;margin:0 0 8px;vertical-align:middle}}

</style>
  </head>
  <body class="light">
    <!-- Widget Loader -->
    <div id="tp-widget-loader" class="tp-widget-loader tp-rebrand-stars tp-rebrand-stars--5 tp-widget-loader--loaded"></div>

    <div id="tp-widget-wrapper" class="tp-widget-wrapper visible">
      <a id="profile-link" target="_blank" href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.mipagina.com?utm_medium=trustbox&amp;utm_source=MicroStar">
        <!-- Human Score -->
        <div id="trust-score" class="tp-widget-trustscore">Great</div>
        <!-- Stars -->
        <div id="tp-widget-stars" class="tp-widget-stars"><div class=""><div class="tp-stars tp-stars--4">
  <div style="position: relative; height: 0; width: 100%; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 18.326693227091635%;">
    
  <svg viewBox="0 0 251 46" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;">
      <g class="tp-star">
          <path class="tp-star__canvas" fill="#dcdce6" d="M0 46.330002h46.375586V0H0z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__shape" d="M39.533936 19.711433L13.230239 38.80065l3.838216-11.797827L7.02115 19.711433h12.418975l3.837417-11.798624 3.837418 11.798624h12.418975zM23.2785 31.510075l7.183595-1.509576 2.862114 8.800152L23.2785 31.510075z" fill="#FFF"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="tp-star">
          <path class="tp-star__canvas" fill="#dcdce6" d="M51.24816 46.330002h46.375587V0H51.248161z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__canvas--half" fill="#dcdce6" d="M51.24816 46.330002h23.187793V0H51.248161z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__shape" d="M74.990978 31.32991L81.150908 30 84 39l-9.660206-7.202786L64.30279 39l3.895636-11.840666L58 19.841466h12.605577L74.499595 8l3.895637 11.841466H91L74.990978 31.329909z" fill="#FFF"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="tp-star">
          <path class="tp-star__canvas" fill="#dcdce6" d="M102.532209 46.330002h46.375586V0h-46.375586z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__canvas--half" fill="#dcdce6" d="M102.532209 46.330002h23.187793V0h-23.187793z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__shape" d="M142.066994 19.711433L115.763298 38.80065l3.838215-11.797827-10.047304-7.291391h12.418975l3.837418-11.798624 3.837417 11.798624h12.418975zM125.81156 31.510075l7.183595-1.509576 2.862113 8.800152-10.045708-7.290576z" fill="#FFF"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="tp-star">
          <path class="tp-star__canvas" fill="#dcdce6" d="M153.815458 46.330002h46.375586V0h-46.375586z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__canvas--half" fill="#dcdce6" d="M153.815458 46.330002h23.187793V0h-23.187793z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__shape" d="M193.348355 19.711433L167.045457 38.80065l3.837417-11.797827-10.047303-7.291391h12.418974l3.837418-11.798624 3.837418 11.798624h12.418974zM177.09292 31.510075l7.183595-1.509576 2.862114 8.800152-10.045709-7.290576z" fill="#FFF"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="tp-star">
          <path class="tp-star__canvas" fill="#dcdce6" d="M205.064416 46.330002h46.375587V0h-46.375587z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__canvas--half" fill="#dcdce6" d="M205.064416 46.330002h23.187793V0h-23.187793z"></path>
          <path class="tp-star__shape" d="M244.597022 19.711433l-26.3029 19.089218 3.837419-11.797827-10.047304-7.291391h12.418974l3.837418-11.798624 3.837418 11.798624h12.418975zm-16.255436 11.798642l7.183595-1.509576 2.862114 8.800152-10.045709-7.290576z" fill="#FFF"></path>
      </g>
  </svg>
  </div>
</div></div></div>
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div id="tp-widget-logo" class="tp-widget-logo"><div class="">
  <div style="position: relative; height: 0; width: 100%; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 24.6031746031746%;">
    
  <svg viewBox="0 0 126 31" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;">
      <title>Trustpilot</title>
      <path class="tp-logo__text" d="M33.074774 11.07005H45.81806v2.364196h-5.010656v13.290316h-2.755306V13.434246h-4.988435V11.07005h.01111zm12.198892 4.319629h2.355341v2.187433h.04444c.077771-.309334.222203-.60762.433295-.894859.211092-.287239.466624-.56343.766597-.79543.299972-.243048.633276-.430858.999909-.585525.366633-.14362.744377-.220953 1.12212-.220953.288863 0 .499955.011047.611056.022095.1111.011048.222202.033143.344413.04419v2.408387c-.177762-.033143-.355523-.055238-.544395-.077333-.188872-.022096-.366633-.033143-.544395-.033143-.422184 0-.822148.08838-1.199891.254096-.377744.165714-.699936.41981-.977689.740192-.277753.331429-.499955.729144-.666606 1.21524-.166652.486097-.244422 1.03848-.244422 1.668195v5.39125h-2.510883V15.38968h.01111zm18.220567 11.334883H61.02779v-1.579813h-.04444c-.311083.574477-.766597 1.02743-1.377653 1.369908-.611055.342477-1.233221.51924-1.866497.51924-1.499864 0-2.588654-.364573-3.25526-1.104765-.666606-.740193-.999909-1.856005-.999909-3.347437V15.38968h2.510883v6.948968c0 .994288.188872 1.701337.577725 2.1101.377744.408763.922139.618668 1.610965.618668.533285 0 .96658-.077333 1.322102-.243048.355524-.165714.644386-.37562.855478-.65181.222202-.265144.377744-.596574.477735-.972194.09999-.37562.144431-.784382.144431-1.226288v-6.573349h2.510883v11.323836zm4.27739-3.634675c.07777.729144.355522 1.237336.833257 1.535623.488844.287238 1.06657.441905 1.744286.441905.233312 0 .499954-.022095.799927-.055238.299973-.033143.588836-.110476.844368-.209905.266642-.099429.477734-.254096.655496-.452954.166652-.198857.244422-.452953.233312-.773335-.01111-.320381-.133321-.585525-.355523-.784382-.222202-.209906-.499955-.364573-.844368-.497144-.344413-.121525-.733267-.232-1.17767-.320382-.444405-.088381-.888809-.18781-1.344323-.287239-.466624-.099429-.922138-.232-1.355432-.37562-.433294-.14362-.822148-.342477-1.166561-.596573-.344413-.243048-.622166-.56343-.822148-.950097-.211092-.386668-.311083-.861716-.311083-1.436194 0-.618668.155542-1.12686.455515-1.54667.299972-.41981.688826-.75124 1.14434-1.005336.466624-.254095.97769-.430858 1.544304-.541334.566615-.099429 1.11101-.154667 1.622075-.154667.588836 0 1.15545.066286 1.688736.18781.533285.121524 1.02213.320381 1.455423.60762.433294.276191.788817.640764 1.07768 1.08267.288863.441905.466624.98324.544395 1.612955h-2.621984c-.122211-.596572-.388854-1.005335-.822148-1.204193-.433294-.209905-.933248-.309334-1.488753-.309334-.177762 0-.388854.011048-.633276.04419-.244422.033144-.466624.088382-.688826.165715-.211092.077334-.388854.198858-.544395.353525-.144432.154667-.222203.353525-.222203.60762 0 .309335.111101.552383.322193.740193.211092.18781.488845.342477.833258.475048.344413.121524.733267.232 1.177671.320382.444404.088381.899918.18781 1.366542.287239.455515.099429.899919.232 1.344323.37562.444404.14362.833257.342477 1.17767.596573.344414.254095.622166.56343.833258.93905.211092.37562.322193.850668.322193 1.40305 0 .673906-.155541 1.237336-.466624 1.712385-.311083.464001-.711047.850669-1.199891 1.137907-.488845.28724-1.04435.508192-1.644295.640764-.599946.132572-1.199891.198857-1.788727.198857-.722156 0-1.388762-.077333-1.999818-.243048-.611056-.165714-1.14434-.408763-1.588745-.729144-.444404-.33143-.799927-.740192-1.05546-1.226289-.255532-.486096-.388853-1.071621-.411073-1.745528h2.533103v-.022095zm8.288135-7.700208h1.899828v-3.402675h2.510883v3.402675h2.26646v1.867052h-2.26646v6.054109c0 .265143.01111.486096.03333.684954.02222.18781.07777.353524.155542.486096.07777.132572.199981.232.366633.298287.166651.066285.377743.099428.666606.099428.177762 0 .355523 0 .533285-.011047.177762-.011048.355523-.033143.533285-.077334v1.933338c-.277753.033143-.555505.055238-.811038.088381-.266642.033143-.533285.04419-.811037.04419-.666606 0-1.199891-.066285-1.599855-.18781-.399963-.121523-.722156-.309333-.944358-.552381-.233313-.243049-.377744-.541335-.466625-.905907-.07777-.364573-.13332-.784383-.144431-1.248384v-6.683825h-1.899827v-1.889147h-.02222zm8.454788 0h2.377562V16.9253h.04444c.355523-.662858.844368-1.12686 1.477644-1.414098.633276-.287239 1.310992-.430858 2.055369-.430858.899918 0 1.677625.154667 2.344231.475048.666606.309335 1.222111.740193 1.666515 1.292575.444405.552382.766597 1.193145.9888 1.92229.222202.729145.333303 1.513527.333303 2.3421 0 .762288-.099991 1.50248-.299973 2.20953-.199982.718096-.499955 1.347812-.899918 1.900194-.399964.552383-.911029.98324-1.533194 1.31467-.622166.33143-1.344323.497144-2.18869.497144-.366634 0-.733267-.033143-1.0999-.099429-.366634-.066286-.722157-.176762-1.05546-.320381-.333303-.14362-.655496-.33143-.933249-.56343-.288863-.232-.522175-.497144-.722157-.79543h-.04444v5.656393h-2.510883V15.38968zm8.77698 5.67849c0-.508193-.06666-1.005337-.199981-1.491433-.133321-.486096-.333303-.905907-.599946-1.281527-.266642-.37562-.599945-.673906-.988799-.894859-.399963-.220953-.855478-.342477-1.366542-.342477-1.05546 0-1.855387.364572-2.388672 1.093717-.533285.729144-.799928 1.701337-.799928 2.916578 0 .574478.066661 1.104764.211092 1.59086.144432.486097.344414.905908.633276 1.259432.277753.353525.611056.629716.99991.828574.388853.209905.844367.309334 1.355432.309334.577725 0 1.05546-.121524 1.455423-.353525.399964-.232.722157-.541335.97769-.905907.255531-.37562.444403-.79543.555504-1.270479.099991-.475049.155542-.961145.155542-1.458289zm4.432931-9.99812h2.510883v2.364197h-2.510883V11.07005zm0 4.31963h2.510883v11.334883h-2.510883V15.389679zm4.755124-4.31963h2.510883v15.654513h-2.510883V11.07005zm10.210184 15.963847c-.911029 0-1.722066-.154667-2.433113-.452953-.711046-.298287-1.310992-.718097-1.810946-1.237337-.488845-.530287-.866588-1.160002-1.12212-1.889147-.255533-.729144-.388854-1.535622-.388854-2.408386 0-.861716.133321-1.657147.388853-2.386291.255533-.729145.633276-1.35886 1.12212-1.889148.488845-.530287 1.0999-.93905 1.810947-1.237336.711047-.298286 1.522084-.452953 2.433113-.452953.911028 0 1.722066.154667 2.433112.452953.711047.298287 1.310992.718097 1.810947 1.237336.488844.530287.866588 1.160003 1.12212 1.889148.255532.729144.388854 1.524575.388854 2.38629 0 .872765-.133322 1.679243-.388854 2.408387-.255532.729145-.633276 1.35886-1.12212 1.889147-.488845.530287-1.0999.93905-1.810947 1.237337-.711046.298286-1.522084.452953-2.433112.452953zm0-1.977528c.555505 0 1.04435-.121524 1.455423-.353525.411074-.232.744377-.541335 1.01102-.916954.266642-.37562.455513-.806478.588835-1.281527.12221-.475049.188872-.961145.188872-1.45829 0-.486096-.066661-.961144-.188872-1.44724-.122211-.486097-.322193-.905907-.588836-1.281527-.266642-.37562-.599945-.673907-1.011019-.905907-.411074-.232-.899918-.353525-1.455423-.353525-.555505 0-1.04435.121524-1.455424.353525-.411073.232-.744376.541334-1.011019.905907-.266642.37562-.455514.79543-.588835 1.281526-.122211.486097-.188872.961145-.188872 1.447242 0 .497144.06666.98324.188872 1.458289.12221.475049.322193.905907.588835 1.281527.266643.37562.599946.684954 1.01102.916954.411073.243048.899918.353525 1.455423.353525zm6.4883-9.66669h1.899827v-3.402674h2.510883v3.402675h2.26646v1.867052h-2.26646v6.054109c0 .265143.01111.486096.03333.684954.02222.18781.07777.353524.155541.486096.077771.132572.199982.232.366634.298287.166651.066285.377743.099428.666606.099428.177762 0 .355523 0 .533285-.011047.177762-.011048.355523-.033143.533285-.077334v1.933338c-.277753.033143-.555505.055238-.811038.088381-.266642.033143-.533285.04419-.811037.04419-.666606 0-1.199891-.066285-1.599855-.18781-.399963-.121523-.722156-.309333-.944358-.552381-.233313-.243049-.377744-.541335-.466625-.905907-.07777-.364573-.133321-.784383-.144431-1.248384v-6.683825h-1.899827v-1.889147h-.02222z" fill="#191919"></path>
      <path class="tp-logo__star" fill="#00B67A" d="M30.141707 11.07005H18.63164L15.076408.177071l-3.566342 10.892977L0 11.059002l9.321376 6.739063-3.566343 10.88193 9.321375-6.728016 9.310266 6.728016-3.555233-10.88193 9.310266-6.728016z"></path>
      <path class="tp-logo__star-notch" fill="#005128" d="M21.631369 20.26169l-.799928-2.463625-5.755033 4.153914z"></path>
  </svg>
  </div>
</div></div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Error Fallback -->
    
    <script src="main.js" async="" defer=""></script>
  

</body></html>
```

Comment: Aparentemente, los widgets de TrustPilot [pueden ser customizados](https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/203840826-Add-a-TrustBox-widget-to-a-webpage#customize-trustbox-4), pero es bastante limitado.

Comment: Correcto. Es bastante limitado lo que podes hacer y los contacte para hacerles esta pregunta y no tienen idea básicamente...

Answer (score 0):

No es posible editar html y css en un `iframe`. Eso sería un gran riesgo de seguridad. Puedes usar javascript para editar el html o el css en el `widget`. Como aquí:

```js
const widget = document.getElementById('trustpilot-widget').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

widget.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div class="trustpilot-widget" id="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="blablabla" data-businessunit-id="blablabla" data-style-height="24px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light">
  <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.mipagina.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los elementos a los que quiere acceder no son directos de su DOM, sino que se le genera un `iframe`. Investigándolo he encontrado [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe) artículo, es más complejo de lo que parece.